# Implement serial in to parallel out shift register with AVR microcontroller

Tags: avr, bit-shift

On the internet there are quite a number of tutorials of how to control a shift register with a microcontroller, but is it actually possible to implement the shift register function with only the microcontroller?

Answer (score 1):

If you have enough pins, I don't see why the naive way wouldn't work...

For an *n*-bit shift in register, you need *n*+2 pins:

- One clock-in
- One data-in
- *n* data-out

The pseudocode of the implementation is:

```
var byte r := 0 // Assuming n=8, so 8 bits fit into a single byte
var byte i := 0

forever:
  wait for clock-in = low
  wait for clock-in = high
  r := r << 0 | data-in
  i := i + 1
  if i = n:
    data-out<1..n> := r
    i = 0
```

If you want to make sure that `data-out` is updated synchronously, make sure you use pins of a single port: then the `data-out<1..n> := r` statement can literally be a single port register assignment.

If you want to run this concurrently with other code, you should be able to use a pin for `clock-in` that can trigger an interrupt.

Comment: may be an additional latch input